# Using NAs with model.matrix

Tags: r

Let's say I have a variable and I would like to generate dummy variables from it. `model.matrix` is very helpful

```
model.matrix(~iris$Species-1)
```

But let's say I have missing values

```
iris$Species[1]=NA
model.matrix(~iris$Species-1)
```

The only difference between these two model.matrix outputs is that the second one omits the row with the NA. I would like `model.matrix` to treat NA as a unique value, and create an additional column for NAs.

Is there an efficient way of doing this or will I have to write a function to do it?

Comment: I don't want to be condescending, but what do you want to do with the dummy variables? If it's for a model, creating them is very often not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution might be to convert your variable of interest to a factor, and don't exclude NA while doing that:

```
iris$Species[1] <- NA
mm2 <- model.matrix(~factor(iris$Species, exclude=NULL)-1)
>dim(mm2)
150   4
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for.